# How would I put a shortcode into php code?

Tags: php, wordpress

Working on a Wordpress site. I need to add a shortcode into one of the php files (replacing a search bar code that is hardcoded into the header php file). How do I add a shortcode to the header php file?

This is the code that I am looking at:

```
<?php if ( (is_front_page()) && (of_get_option('g_search_box_id') == 'yes') ) { ?>
    <div class="search-form-wrap hidden-phone" data-motopress-type="static" data-motopress-static-file="static/static-search.php">
        <?php get_template_part("static/static-search"); ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

and I need to remove the search-form-wrap with a different shortcode search form (for mls).

Comment: You want to run a certain shortcode from PHP?
So that your search box would be the same that the shortcode [searchbox_tag] would produce from within a post?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

To run short-code from a php file. We use do_shortcode function e.g:

```
// Use shortcodes in form like Landing Page Template.
echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="91" title="quote"]' );
```

Comment: Okay, but where do I put that? Right after the <?php   ?

Comment: @damann if you want to replace the <?php get_template_part("static/static-search"); ?> .. then replace get_template_part line with the do_shortcode statement.